# why my logo is visible in all browsers but not visible in their print views

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm stuck with a problem. I need to print the page with the logo but the problem is that the logo is shown in the browser but in the print preview (CTRL P) the logo is not displayed.

For any guidance I would be very thankful.

[image]

This is the html code and css media print code

```css
/* @@ removed here since they are specific to ASP.NET MVC */

@media print {
  @page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .prints {
    height: 19.2cm;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    border: black 1px solid;
  }
  .row {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}


/*! Generated by Font Squirrel (https://www.fontsquirrel.com) on July 30, 2018 */

label {
  font: c
}
```

```html
<table align="center" style="padding-left:10px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <h4 style="text-align:center;padding-left:25px; font-family:Calibri"><b> CHALLAN FORM </b></h4>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <label style="padding-left:10px;width:145px;">
              <span style="line-height:1; width: 135px; font-size:26px; font-family:'Chursaechsische Fraktur';"><strong>Baitul Huda</strong></span>
              <span style="line-height:1;border:0px; width:100px; font-size:12px; font-family:'Adobe Devanagari';">High School For Girls</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width:30px;padding-right:0px; padding-left: 10px;">
        <img src="~/images/nku_02.png" height="70" width="70" alt="Bail ul huda logo" />
      </td>
      <td style="padding-left:10px;">
        <div style="padding-left:5px;">
          <label style="width:120px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">
              <span style="line-height:0; width: 160px; font-size:26px; font-family:'UL Sajid Heading';">بیت الھدیٰ</span>
              <span style="line-height:1; width:100px;padding-left:10px; font-size:16px; font-family:'Al Qalam Quran 2A';">    ھایئ سکول فارگرلز</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: That can have a lot of reasons. But witout providing any info we are not able to help you. Take a look at this and edit your question please:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: check if css you need for the print is not wrapped in @media screen in your css.

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: Why double @? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: my .htmlcs file not picking single @

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your HTML, but the most glaring is that you have `colspan="3"` on your first `td`, and then have two blank `td`, so your subsequent rows should have a total of 5 columns in order for that to work (or their own `colspan` attributes); you have three columns in the next row, none with `colspan` attributes. Therefore the cell with the image is shrunk down. Also, you've specified the width of the cell containing the image to be `30px` and the width of the image to be `70`, which won't work well together.

Comment: is the logo white in color?

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok you right  but logo is apear in browser but on print preview it disapear

Comment: Maybe you should try fully qualified image url instead of relative path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution
Img is not coming in print view because there is a missing of a `div`

```html
<td rowspan="2">
      <div style="padding-left:10px;width:80px;height:50px">
            <img src="/images/offical_Logo_Baitul_Huda.jpeg" class="img-responsive" style="height:50px ; width:100px" alt="">
      </div>
</td>
```

As i add the div the logo start displayed in print view